# Marklogic 8 Windows 7 post-install login

Tags: marklogic

I have installed MarkLogic 8 on a 64bit Windows 7 machine with 8Gb memory... the server seems to run fine....all seems to be fine except for my ability to login.

A login box appears on a blank browser page when using either the 'Use Marklogic Server' or Admin Marklogic Server' program shortcuts, which asks for a username and password for http://127.0.0.1:8001.  My credentials do not seem to be working and I created a new admin account which is unrecognized as well.

I know this is very rudimentary and that I must be missing something simple.  I would appreciate a little guidance.  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael, it sounds like MarkLogic is up and running. It sounds like after installing, you went to port 8001 and did the [standard setup](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_60220), which includes creating a MarkLogic admin account. The username and password provided in that step is what the browser is asking for now. Since you're not getting past that, my best guess is a typo, perhaps when you set the password.

Assuming that's the case, and that you can't figure out the password, the simplest thing is to start over (I'm also assuming that you have not done any database configuration or entered data). The following procedure **WILL REMOVE ANY DATA**.

- Shut down MarkLogic
- Remove the c:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data directory (THIS WILL DELETE CONFIGURATION AND DATA)
- Start up MarkLogic

MarkLogic will see that the data directory is missing and recreate it, triggering the standard setup process again. That includes entering a new admin password.

Comment: Dave...  Thanks so much!  I got there at the same time as your answer arrived....by uninstalling (completely) and rerunning the install process.  I must have messed up the initial admin username and password on initial install... or my upgrading memory in parallel to all this caused some other issue.  In any case, all is working and I am successfully at the Administration console.  Thanks again!